# How to find a string among many strings in a line

Tags: python, string

I have a requirement to find the user from the log.

I have a line of code from my log file. One of the strings in the line is a userid. I have the list of all userid also.

Is there any easy way to identify the userid mentioned in the line.

**Eg:** `Calling Business function ProcessSOMBFCommitment_Sourcing from F4211FSEditLine for ND9074524. Application Name [P421002], Version [] (BSFNLevel = 3)`

Here, `ND9074525` is the user id. My intention is to identify the user from the line.

Other possible userid can be `AB9074158`, `AC9074168`, `AD9074123`, `AE9074152`

I do not want to loop through all the possible userid. I thought of creating a list of all userid's and find the userid used in line by some method. Not sure if it exists.

Comment: Do userids follow any particular pattern, and if so, what is it?

Comment: yes, two alphabets followed by 7 digits.

Comment: Two whole alphabets? Oh wait: two letters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex to fetch the user id:

```
[A-Z]{2}\d{7}
```

And then check against valid user ids.

[Regex Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/lIMXkW/1)

---

**Code:**

```
import re

users = ['AB9074158', 'AC9074168', 'AD9074123', 'AE9074152']
s = 'Calling Business function ProcessSOMBFCommitment_Sourcing from F4211FSEditLine for ND9074524. Application Name [P421002], Version [] (BSFNLevel = 3)'

pat = '[A-Z]{2}\d{7}'
user_id = re.search(pat, s).group(0)

print(user_id)

if user_id in users:
    print("User accepted!")
else:
    print("User not accepted")
```

**Output:**

```
'ND9074524'
'User not accepted'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to find all strings that match the pattern of a userid; then you can see if any of them are actual userids.